# Post 'Featured Image' display bug in Custom theme

Tags: php, wordpress

So I am submitting new custom posts through a front end form which includes an upload option for the featured image. Everything works as intended from start to finish. But, while inside the '**Edit Post**' screen in Wordpress admin dashboard, the featured image thumbnail overflows and appears above the '*Featured Image*' tab. Kind of behaves like an 'absolute positioned' element.

Screenshot of what I mean:
https://ibb.co/qsmKV6d

No CSS has been added by me yet so it's not that.

This is how I am uploading the image:

```
$uploaddir = wp_upload_dir();
$file = $_FILES['post-image']['name'];
$temp = $_FILES['post-image']['tmp_name'];
$uploadfile = $uploaddir['path'] . '/' . basename( $file );

move_uploaded_file( $temp , $uploadfile );
$filename = basename( $uploadfile );

$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null );

$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'menu_order' => $_i + 1000
);
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploadfile );
set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
```

What to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there's a WordPress function for creating attachment via standard file upload form: [`media_handle_upload()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_upload/) — see an example [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_upload/#comment-534), and with that function, your code would be simpler. :)

However, to answer the question, the issue happened because you did not *generate and update the necessary attachment metadata* like `file`, `width`, `height` and the attachment sub-sizes (i.e. intermediate sizes like `medium` and `thumbnail`).

So to fix the issue, you should call [`wp_generate_attachment_metadata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_attachment_metadata/) and [`wp_update_attachment_metadata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_attachment_metadata/) after you called [`wp_insert_attachment()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_attachment/):

```php
// Create an attachment post for the image.
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploadfile );

// Then after that, generate and update the attachment metadata.
$metadata = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $uploadfile );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $metadata );
```

Comment: Works. Thank you so much. But I had to add 3 additional lines:


require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );


Could you by any chance also know how to delete this image from the media page too when I delete the post?

Comment: Yes, you're right, and sorry, I forgot to say that you would need to manually load those files if your code runs outside the `wp-admin` folder. As for deleting the media when the parent post is deleted, you can use [`wp_delete_attachment()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_attachment/) through the [`deleted_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/deleted_post/) or [`after_delete_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/after_delete_post/) action/hook.